# How can I change color of the top bar of a pygame window?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

I am wondering if it is possible to change the color of the top bar of a pygame window. If it is possible please tell me how.

Image of the pygame window:

[image: Here's an image of the top bar.]

Any suggestions would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The short answer is no. Longer answer - You need to access the Windows message pump and override the Paint event.

You're better off just hiding the title bar and drawing your own header:

```
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((640, 480), pygame.NOFRAME)
```